# UTC time to a particular time zone in SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, timezone, utc

I have a date time in my stored procedure which is UTC Time.  I would like this to be converted to local peurto rico time.  My stored procedure will be run in the states and in peurto rico.  I want the resultset time to be peurto rico time?

Comment: Which dbms? (Many dbms products have their own ways for stored procedures and time/timezones...)

Comment: Oh sorry its. SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my research is correct then Puerto Rico does not use DST (daylight saving time) so will always be 4 hours behind UTC, so a simple `DATEADD(hour, -4, YourColumn)` should work. See the MSDN page on [DATEADD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) for more info.

Comment: That is correct. [Puerto Rico does not observe DST](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/puerto-rico/san-juan).

Comment: Yes. That's it! The above DATEADD function seems to be the solution. Thank you.